# How to use dept and $arrayElemAt in the same query in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, collections, aggregate, lookup, aggregation

I was trying to find a particular type of variable "nazwa" in collection "zespoly" using lookup function. Variable's type is "SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE". I've also tried using $match, but it didn't work. Until now I can only write a code which shows all the types. Could you help me with that one?

It's sample input of collection "pracownicy":

```js
db.pracownicy.find()
{ _id: ObjectId("61241fa38c142ccb2b98cd7e"),
  id_prac: 100,
  nazwisko: 'WEGLARZ',
  etat: 'DYREKTOR',
  zatrudniony: 1968-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
  placa_pod: 2730,
  placa_dod: 420.5,
  id_zesp: 10 }
{ _id: ObjectId("61241fa38c142ccb2b98cd7f"),
  id_prac: 110,
  nazwisko: 'BLAZEWICZ',
  etat: 'PROFESOR',
  id_szefa: 100,
  zatrudniony: 1973-05-01T00:00:00.000Z,
  placa_pod: 1850,
  placa_dod: 100,
  id_zesp: 40 }
```

This is sample input of "zespoly" collection:

```js
db.zespoly.find()
{ _id: ObjectId("612420218c142ccb2b98cd8c"),
  id_zesp: 10,
  nazwa: 'ADMINISTRACJA',
  adres: 'PIOTROWO 3A' }
{ _id: ObjectId("612420218c142ccb2b98cd8d"),
  id_zesp: 20,
  nazwa: 'SYSTEMY ROZPROSZONE',
  adres: 'PIOTROWO 3A' }
{ _id: ObjectId("612420218c142ccb2b98cd8e"),
  id_zesp: 30,
  nazwa: 'SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE',
  adres: 'STRZELECKA 14' }
```

My code:

```js
db.pracownicy.aggregate(
[{$lookup:{from: "zespoly",
localField: "id_zesp",
 foreignField: "id_zesp",
 as: "dept"}},
 {$project: {_id:0,"id_zesp":1,"nazwisko":1, "dept": {$arrayElemAt:["$dept.nazwa",0]}}}
]
)
```

That is what I got:

```js
{ nazwisko: 'WEGLARZ', id_zesp: 10, dept: 'ADMINISTRACJA' }
{ nazwisko: 'BLAZEWICZ', id_zesp: 40, dept: 'ALGORYTMY' }
{ nazwisko: 'SLOWINSKI',
  id_zesp: 30,
  dept: 'SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE' }
{ nazwisko: 'BRZEZINSKI',
  id_zesp: 20,
  dept: 'SYSTEMY ROZPROSZONE' }
{ nazwisko: 'MORZY', id_zesp: 20, dept: 'SYSTEMY ROZPROSZONE' }
{ nazwisko: 'KROLIKOWSKI',
  id_zesp: 20,
  dept: 'SYSTEMY ROZPROSZONE' }
{ nazwisko: 'KOSZLAJDA',
  id_zesp: 20,
  dept: 'SYSTEMY ROZPROSZONE' }
{ nazwisko: 'JEZIERSKI',
  id_zesp: 20,
  dept: 'SYSTEMY ROZPROSZONE' }
{ nazwisko: 'MATYSIAK',
  id_zesp: 20,
  dept: 'SYSTEMY ROZPROSZONE' }
{ nazwisko: 'MAREK', id_zesp: 10, dept: 'ADMINISTRACJA' }
{ nazwisko: 'ZAKRZEWICZ',
  id_zesp: 30,
  dept: 'SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE' }
{ nazwisko: 'BIALY', id_zesp: 30, dept: 'SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE' }
{ nazwisko: 'KONOPKA', id_zesp: 20, dept: 'SYSTEMY ROZPROSZONE' }
{ nazwisko: 'HAPKE', id_zesp: 30, dept: 'SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE' }
```

And this is what I would like to get:

```js
{ nazwisko: 'SLOWINSKI',id_zesp: 30, dept: 'SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE' 
    { nazwisko: 'ZAKRZEWICZ',id_zesp: 30, dept: 'SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE' }
    { nazwisko: 'BIALY', id_zesp: 30, dept: 'SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE' }
    { nazwisko: 'HAPKE', id_zesp: 30, dept: 'SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE' }
```

Comment: Some sample input and expected output would really help.

Answer (score 1):

In your existing aggregation pipeline, add a `$match` stage after the lookup, like:

```
{$match: {"dept.nazwa": "SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE"}}
```

Note that as written the aggregation pipeline will examine every document in  pracownicy whether there is a matching dept or not.

If you were to switch that around to aggregate on zespoly, you could reduce the number of documents examined, which may help performance:

```
db.zespoly.aggregate([
  {$match: { nazwa: "SYSTEMY EKSPERCKIE"}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "pracownicy",
      localField: "id_zesp",
      foreignField: "id_zesp",
      as: "looked"
  }},
  {$unwind: "$looked"},
  {$project: {
      nazwisko: "$looked.nazwisko",
      id_zesp: "$id_zesp",
      dept: "$nazwa"
  }}
])
```